# How to make a cell change color based on the expiry dates from whole column

Tags: excel

Can I make a formula so that a week earlier than the dates from the column the cell in yellow glows red. The idea is to connect all the highlighted cells in one sheet as a linked picture.

[image]

I tried with Conditional format, but I can't get it to consider the whole column.

Answer (score 1):

Type this formula in the yellowish cell and set the range (F5:F8) to the full range of data.
Set the yellowish cell's conditional format to `Highlight Cells Rules Equal to "yes"`

```
=IF(SUM(--(F5:F8-7=TODAY()))>=1;"Yes";"No")
```